# Batch scripting programfag

Tags: batch-file, echo, batch-processing

the first time this is run, then the user can choose what kind of program they have in their school.

Then (as you look further down in the source code) will come with the date of the first test of various subjects.

If I use this on, it will print the program subjects that I have not.
Forexample if I have "jurisprudence(rettslere)" and not "marketing", I do not want marketing(markedsforing) to be found by the program subjects, but only "jurisprudence". Thus it should ignore all of the program courses I have not.

How do I do this?¨

Spesific question: How do i do so it wont output the program`s lessions that is not in the programfag.txt file?

program`s:

```
echo Rettslære (R)
echo sosialkunnskap (s)
echo markedsforing (m)
echo historie og filosofi (hf)
echo sosialantropologi (sa)
echo psykologi (p)
```

code:

```
    @echo off &setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if not exist "%userprofile%/programfag.txt" goto programfag
goto hello


:programfag

echo Rettslære (R)
echo sosialkunnskap (s)
echo markedsforing (m)
echo historie og filosofi (hf)
echo sosialantropologi (sa)
echo psykologi (p)

set /p programfag=What is your programfag (r,s,m,hf,sa,p)?

if %programfag% == r echo rettslare > %userprofile%/programfag.txt
if %programfag% == m echo markedsforing > %userprofile%/programfag.txt
if %programfag% == s echo sosialkunnskap > %userprofile%/programfag.txt
if %programfag% == hf echo Historieogfilosofi > %userprofile%/programfag.txt
if %programfag% == sa echo sosialantropologi > %userprofile%/programfag.txt
if %programfag% == p echo psykologi > %userprofile%/programfag.txt

goto programfag




:hello
set "file_path=.\test2.txt"

if not exist "!file_path!" echo File "!file_path!" Does Not Exist >&2 & exit /b 2
for /f %%F in ("!file_path!") do  set file_path=%%~sfF


copy nul "%TEMP%\~.ddf" >nul

makecab /D RptFileName="%TEMP%\~.rpt" /D InfFileName="%TEMP%\~.inf" -f "%TEMP%\~.ddf">nul
for /f "tokens=3-7" %%a in ('type "%TEMP%\~.rpt"') do (
   if not defined current-date set "current-date=%%e-%%b-%%c"
   if not defined current-time set "current-time=%%d"
   if not defined weekday set "weekday=%%a"
)
del /q "%TEMP%\~.*"
rem echo %weekday% %current-date% %current-time%
set Jan=01
set Feb=02
set Mar=03
set Apr=04
set May=05
set Jun=06
set Jul=07
set Aug=08
set Sep=09
Set Oct=10
set Nov=11
set Dec=12
set auth=Malin Kristiane Pedersen
set abas=0
set auto=%abas%

for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=-" %%A in ("%current-date%") do (
    set comparable_date=%%A!%%B!%%C
)
rem echo %comparable_date%
set /a nearest_date=99999999
for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=. " %%A in (%file_path%) do (

    set /a possible_nearest_date=%%C%%B%%A

    set /a old_result=!nearest_date!-comparable_date
    set /a new_result=!possible_nearest_date!-comparable_date

    if !new_result! LSS !old_result! set /a nearest_date=!possible_nearest_date!
)
if !nearest_date! EQU 99999999 echo something wrong with the file>&2 && endlocal && exit /b 3

set nearest_date=!nearest_date:~-2!.!nearest_date:~4,2!.!nearest_date:~0,4!
color 4E

echo(
echo(
rem type %file_path%
for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=()" %%L in ('type %file_path%^|find "!nearest_date!"') do ( 

    for /f "tokens=1,2" %%t in  ("%%L") do (

                echo              Neste prove: (!nearest_date!^)   
             echo                    fag:  %%u   
title %%u !nearest_date!                                                 grunder: %auth%        
              echo          Tema:   %%M^ )                      

    )   
)
echo(
echo(
set /p skriva=Do you want to see typical questions about this topic? (Y/N)
if %skriva% EQU Y goto !nearest_date!sporsmaal
if %skriva% EQU y goto !nearest_date!sporsmaal
else
pause>nul
cls



goto hello
exit


:28.10.2013sporsmaal
echo AAA
echo BBB
echo CCC
echo DDD
echo EEE

pause
exit
```

here is where the output comes:

```
     if !nearest_date! EQU 99999999 echo something wrong with the file>&2 && endlocal && exit /b 3

set nearest_date=!nearest_date:~-2!.!nearest_date:~4,2!.!nearest_date:~0,4! color 4E

echo( echo( rem type %file_path% for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=()" %%L in ('type %file_path%^|find "!nearest_date!"') do (

for /f "tokens=1,2" %%t in  ("%%L") do (

            echo              Neste prove: (!nearest_date!^)   
         echo                    fag:  %%u   
title %%u !nearest_date! grunder: %auth% 
echo Tema: %%M^ )

)   
) echo( echo(
```

note:

example in test2.txt:

```
28.10.2013 Norsk (kunnskapsprøve).
29.10.2013 matte (prøve kapittel 1 og kapittel 3,1 - 3,6).
```

example in programfag.txt

```
markedsforing
```

as i said, i would like when the fag ( in the source code) is showed, when its looking in program`s, it will only show the one that its the same as in programfag.txt

Comment: You might have more luck getting an answer if you can distill a smaller, more specific question out of this. Can you find how far things get before they go "wrong" ? (You might also find batch isn't the most appropriate language for this kind of high-level script, but that's really up to you).

Comment: Edited it a bit now.

yeah, batch isnt the most appropriate language for this kind, but that is what i have to use for now.

Comment: I recommend you try python. Its not hard to grasp the basics, and its free. Its also great for this sort of stuff. And if required you can use commands from cmd, as well as external programs. http://www.trypython.org/ for a quick tutorial

Comment: I will look into Python, But as this is going to be launched from a school computer, with limitations, i really need this to be done in batch.

Comment: Can you clarify the task?  You seem to have the list above in `programs:` and you want to echo only the lines that are in another file.  Is that right?  Can you give an example of what is inside that other file? `"%userprofile%/programfag.txt"`

Comment: sure. in the another file (test2) it`s like:

28.10.2013 Norsk (kunnskapsprøve). (NEW LINE)
29.10.2013 matte (prøve kapittel 1 og kapittel 3,1 - 3,6). (NEW LINE)


 means, in the program the %%U / fag is like (here it is norsk, matte), and the program`s is gonna be in the %%u / fag.

edit: well, in the programfag.txt is gonna be the name on the program they have. ( so i want it to load from that file, and then only show the program that the person have / thats inside the file, and not the another program`s.

Comment: Put an example of the file in your question, if that is the actual problem that you only want to show the list that is inside this file.

Comment: The items in the example file do not appear in the batch file - do they?  BTW `fag` is not an English term for anything relating to academic studies.

Comment: THe examples is from the another files, ( the filenames are used in the batch file). Sorry, i forgot to translate fag. Fag in this case is from my native language norwegian. Fag means subject .

Comment: You might be amused to know that fag in English is slang for a Homosexual.  I've posted some code that might help.

Answer (score 0):

Backup the `"%userprofile%/programfag.txt"` file and try this.  It only prints what is found in the `"%userprofile%/programfag.txt"` file.

```
@echo off

>>"%userprofile%/programfag.txt" echo 11/22/2000 sosialkunnskap
>>"%userprofile%/programfag.txt" echo 4/12/2010 historie og filosofi

:programfag

for %%a in (
"Rettslære (R)"
"sosialkunnskap (s)"
"markedsforing (m)"
"historie og filosofi (hf)"
"sosialantropologi (sa)"
"psykologi (p)"
) do for /f "delims= " %%b in ("%%~a") do find "%%b" <"%userprofile%/programfag.txt" >nul && echo %%~a
pause
```

Comment: well, the programfag.txt file only includes the name on the persons program.

the rest of my file was echoing out the nearest date ( for a test) , from test2.txt, and echo-ed out the fag / %%u). The meaning was if the nearest date and fag ( %%u) included a program that wasnt equal to the persons programfag, it would skip it.  i will test your code now

Comment: The code you posted works, but please read my last comment :)

Comment: I don't understand you comments regarding this file, sorry.

Comment: the first comment i did here, was what i wanted it to do. The date and so on, is located in my test2.txt, , the programfag.txt only contains a spesific program, ( only 1 of them), ( in my main batch file), and if the result ( %%u / fag ) is containing one of the another program, it will skip it. / not be showd.